# switching videoviews

Tags: android, android-videoview

In my activity, i have 2 VideoViews. i have to play different video files continuously one after the other. 
To reduce the switching time, i planned flip the video views. i.e. one video view will be `VISIBLE`, while other is `GONE`. While the visible video view is playing, i can initalize (`setVideoPath`) the other video view.

But based on Logs, i found that for the videoview with visibility `GONE`, after calling `setVideoPath`, the`OnPreparedListener`is called only when the view becomes `VISIBLE`. I.e. after the first videoview completes, i switch the visibility, then i get the `OnPreparedListener`for the 2nd videoview. 

To confirm my findings, i made both videoviews `VISIBLE`and called`setVideoPath`. In this case, both the `OnPreparedListener`are called immediately.

**Question:**
Is the VideoView preparation (`setVideoPath`) dependent on its Visibility?
Is there any way to prepare the videoview in the background (without showing it to user)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through the source code for VideoView and SurfaceView it looks like most of the work of initializing the Media Player doesn't happen until after the view is visible. I don't see a way around that.

In particular, here's the part of SurfaceView.java that runs when the view becomes visible:

```
if (visible) {
    // other stuff
    if (visibleChanged) {
        mIsCreating = true;
        for (SurfaceHolder.Callback c : callbacks) {
            c.surfaceCreated(mSurfaceHolder);
        }
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

That calls this in VideoView.java:

```
SurfaceHolder.Callback mSHCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback()
{
    // other stuff
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        mSurfaceHolder = holder;
        openVideo();
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

And openVideo() is where all the magic happens.

Comment: You could *try* having both VideoViews be visible and using bringToFront() to change which one is on top, but I doubt that will work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the VideoView preparation (setVideoPath) dependent on its Visibility?

Apparently yes. [openVideo()](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java) requires that there is some visibility

```
public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
        mUri = uri;
        mStartWhenPrepared = false;
        mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
        openVideo();
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }
```

> Is there any way to prepare the videoview in the background (without showing it to user)?

Extend this `VideoView` and handle prep yourself. Or just use your own `VideoView`

Comment: I have to use my own video view i guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

View has to be visible  and laid out before it can be bound to camera application.  ( Surface view calbacks shall be processed before you do anything ).